# php 8.1.17, laravel 10, nginx - Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-10

I have already checked most of all answers for this issues, i have not found solution, most of solutions are related to php and apache, i am dealing with nginx, so please don't mark duplicate or already have been answered.

I am using php 8.1.17, laravel 10, and nginx 1.24 for web application, while accessing my application from browser i am getting error

```
"Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()"
```

At php.ini openssl is already enabled, below is my nginx configuration :

```
server {
        listen       8282 ssl;
        #server_name  localhost;
        server_name  abc.example.com:8282;
        client_max_body_size 11M;
        #more_clear_headers Server;
        server_tokens off;
        
        ssl_certificate      example_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  private-key2022.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        
        error_page 404 /html/404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        root /nginx-1.24.0/html;
        internal;
        }
        
        error_page 405 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location = /500.html {
        root /nginx-1.24.0/html;
        internal;
        }
        
        root "E:/project/public";
        index index.php;
        
        if ($request_method ~ ^(OPTIONS|HEAD)$ )
        {
            return 405;
        }
        
        location / {
        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    }
```

In my config/app.php, 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',i used following command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and browse my application still get :

```
"Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()"
```

In my config/app.php, i changed 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC' to 'AES-128-CBC' and run command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Then i browse my application, this time error change to :

```
Unsupported cipher or incorrect key length. Supported ciphers are: aes-128-cbc, aes-256-cbc, aes-128-gcm, aes-256-gcm.
```

Error screenshot below :

[image]

nothing helps, can anyone help to solve this issue ?

when i tried with tinker, openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC') provides output 16.

in php.ini extension_dir is "E:\xampp\php\ext", php --ini output as below :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         E:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Comment: Are you sure openssl is enabled? Did you check phpinfo()?

Comment: Can you show the full trace for that error? It look like it's trying to use the namespace when it's a native function.

Comment: @aynber, I have edited question and added error screen

Comment: @Olivier, Yes it is enabled

Comment: Create a test script with just `openssl_cipher_iv_length();` and run it to see what it gives.

Comment: openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC'), gives me 16

Comment: Did you run the test script via your browser or the command line?

Comment: Run `composer dumpautoload` and try again?

Comment: @Olivier, Via browser

Comment: @aynber, still same

Comment: @user3782114 are you using **docker**?

Comment: @UnderDog, not using docker

Comment: `php artisan tinker`, `openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC')`, update your original question with the output. Open php.ini, find `extension_dir =`, paste what it says In your original question. Update your original question with the output of `php --ini`

Comment: @UnderDog, added in question